# System tray with Java

Tags: java, layout, system-tray

I've set my program to appear in the system tray by doing [what Oracle told to do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html). My first question is about the icon. I have a lot of programs in the system tray and mine is hidden. Can I make it to show in the bar without needing to click the arrow in the tray?

I also figured out that I can display a message by calling `trayIcon.displayMessage(title, content, icon)`. I wonder if I can change the outlook of the balloon in the way Skype has done it.

[image]

Or do I need to use someting else do display a message? It should appear always in the front of all the applications and it shouldn't hinder other applications. For example if the user is playing a game, the information dialog shouldn't steal the focus from mouse and keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cant change the style of the baloon using the java systray mechanism. Skype doesnt use the java mechanism to show the systray. It is the systems task to style and display the baloon.

To show your icon, it is a windows configuration - when you click the arrow, there is a "customize" link, where you can configure which icons are displayed.

If you want to influence the style of the window, you need to implement your custom Frame that feels like and is positioned like a systray info window. And you would not use the Tray classes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I'd like to draw a custom popup alert on the bottom right corner, what would I need to know? Do you have any clues to tell what to search for? 
By the way, the SystemTray way doesn't work when you have fullscreen on.

Comment: I would try to show a JFrame on the bottom right position. So i would search how i get those coordinates. Unfortunately it will always look like a swing frame, unless you draw your own graphics component.

Comment: But wouldn't it interfere with the other applications? Or is there a way to open a JFrame without gaining the focus from keyboard and mouse?

Comment: Also, opening a JFrame will be considered as a program and the status bar will pop up and it starts blinking.

Comment: Yeah, then a swing JFrame is not the solution. Maybe another framework offers this, I didn't do it before, sorry.

Comment: I managed to do it with JPanel though (JFrames appear in taskbar, JPanels don't). I set it to be always on the top and stopped it from gaining focus with `setFocusableWindowState`. The screen size I got with `GraphicsEnvironment` and I calculated the position (width - dialog width, height - dialog height). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your question regarding skinning.  The SystemTray displayMessage balloon can not be  customized in any way.